# Floating image to the right and text to the left?

Tags: html, image

I want to make the image move to the right side and text to the left side. I am doing it with float but I am confused, so I have deleted the code. I only have the HTML code. You can check a screenshot that shows the result I expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WHTg.jpg

HTML:

```
<div class="column2">
  <p class="aboutdes">A quem consectetur, ut dolore non varias, nostrud noster qui expetendis eruditionem, culpa mandaremus non senserit. A magna fugiat dolore pariatur, ab quid consectetur et qui dolore litteris an malis commodo id nostrud</p>.                                                            
</div>
```

Comment: You obviulsy didn't google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML: (I used a sample image)

```
<div class="column2">
    <img src="http://cdn7.facegfx.com/psd/wp-content/uploads/2013/5/6/hd-magical-picture-book-psd.jpg" />  
    <p class="aboutdes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus varius in ligula eget bibendum. Nam faucibus lorem quis mattis rhoncus. Phasellus iaculis felis quis massa molestie rutrum. Praesent elit nisi, facilisis vitae sem eget, faucibus imperdiet elit. Mauris mauris arcu, consectetur in consectetur ac, scelerisque sit amet ante. Nulla ac consequat nibh. Nullam congue massa ipsum, nec venenatis augue semper non. Morbi hendrerit turpis est, eget luctus nulla facilisis sed! Praesent non rhoncus ipsum. Pellentesque lacinia scelerisque rutrum? Donec posuere imperdiet ligula, eget tincidunt metus!
</p>.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column2 > img {
    float: right; 
    width:100px; // or 30% or depends upon your requirement!
    border-radius: 50%; // for the rounded image as shown in your example
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px; // spacing from text
}
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skshoyeb/A47s9/)**

Comment: Exactly that was i wanted. Thanks mate and thanks to all who replying with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just place the `<img />` element inside the `<p>` tag, and then set the following CSS:

```
p > img {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k76ww/)

Comment: If it is for a website where some images are not to be aligned thusly, I would suggest giving the tag a class, e.g. `<p class="imgRight">content<img src="#" /></p>` and then changing `p > img` to `.imgRight`

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<img class="right">` inside the `<p>`. The use

```
img.right { float: right; }
p { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: It's better to target `img` tags specifically inside `<p>` elements, otherwise **all* `<img />` elements will be floated right...

Comment: I guess his example is cut down because of brevity.

Comment: I still need some clarity, for this site seems to promote not-thinking sometimes... But also saying `#your_img` instead of `img` would be more generic too...

Comment: Yep, this will cause alle img elements to float, which you probably don't want. Adding a class or id would fix that.